# How do I display an image on a frame using paintComponent

Tags: exception, graphics, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

This is my code:

```
package com.dani.Game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {

BufferedImage normal;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
}

public Game() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try {
    normal = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\ImageOne.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImagePanel graphics = new ImagePanel();

    this.add(graphics);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(normal,normal.getWidth(), normal.getHeight(), this);

  }
}
```

**Updated:**

When I try this I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread 
     "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.AppContext.get(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.currentManager(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.currentManager(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.currentManager(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at com.course.swing.headPrac$Drawing.paintComponent(headPrac.java:99)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ye and what kind of exception? You didn't even provided exception class.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, this will couse StackOverflow due the calling loop between paint and paintComponent.
replace `super.paint(g)` with `super.paintComponent(g)` as for start.

Its working form me anyway

```
package com.dani.Game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    BufferedImage normal;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            normal = ImageIO.read(new File("d:\\providers.gif"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImagePanel graphics = new ImagePanel();

        this.add(graphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(normal, 0, 0, normal.getWidth(), normal.getHeight(), this);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Antoniossss , When i replace it and run it, it doesn't give an exception , but when it opens the frame, its empty

Comment: So i was right bout the exception. Now try to change layoutmanager of frame to the `BorderLayout` and add your component to it with `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to your code to get it to work properly.

- I made a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method in the main method to make sure the Swing GUI starts on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).  The components of a Swing GUI **must** be defined and used on the EDT.
- I used a JFrame instead of extending a JFrame.  You only extend a Swing component when you want to modify one of its methods.  Otherwise, you use Swing components.
- I used the forward slash in the image file name.  Java will translate the forrward slash to a back slash for Windows.
- I added a call to the JFrame pack method so the JFrame would size itself to the image size.
- I added a call to the setPreferredSize method in the ImagePanel constructor so that the JPanel would be the size of the image.
- I corrected your super call in the paintComponent method to super.paintComponent(g).
- I corrected your drawImage method to use the origin of the image, rather than the size.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game implements Runnable {

    BufferedImage   normal;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Game());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            normal = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/ImageOne.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImagePanel graphics = new ImagePanel();

        frame.add(graphics);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        public ImagePanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(normal.getWidth(),
                    normal.getHeight()));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(normal, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

}
```